# ASP.NET Core 6.0 project works locally, gives System.BadImageFormatException exception when deployed as Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-6.0

**Update 1:** Added screenshot of publish configuration

I created a new project, wrote out the code and debugged it locally (where it works), but when I deploy it to production, I keep getting the following error:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.  Could not load file or assembly 'SDKServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)     at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceIdProvider dataSourceIdProvider, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory, OrderedEndpointsSequenceProvider orderSequence)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
     at Project.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\path\Project\Program.cs:line 65  System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'SDKServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.  File name: 'SDKServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Per whatever I could find on SO and other sites, I've tried the following:

- Full rebuild & redeploy.
- Ensuring that the "bitness" is the same for the main project & all the other projects it depends on (all target *Any CPU*).
- I'm publishing to `win-x86` and the Web App's settings (WebApp | Configuration | General Settings) also shows *Platform* as 32-bit.
- Tried to delete all files via Kudu console and then re-upload (didn't have permission to delete all, but could delete many of the *.dll files)

The configuration of the project is as follows:

- ASP.NET Core 6.0
- The included libraries are as follows:

  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Version="5.1.2"
  NLog Version="5.2.5"
  NLog.Database Version="5.2.5"
  NLog.Extensions.Logging Version="5.2.5"
  NLog.Web.AspNetCore Version="5.2.3"
  Swashbuckle.AspNetCore Version="6.5.0"

Here is the publish configuration I use from Visual Studio:

[image]

Nothing I've tried so far has worked, the error remains the same. If it matters, the error happens when `app.MapControllers()` is invoked in the `Main` method of `Program.cs`.

Comment: Why `win-x68` and not `win-x64`?

Comment: What are the options you have for Configuration .You need to select `Release`.

Comment: @DavidG We are deploying to `win-x86` for all our projects.

Comment: @Harshitha `UAT` is our test configuration and is the right choice in this case. We have many other projects running with `UAT` configuration. We use *Release* when the product is ready for end-users.

Comment: You may need to delete all the files before publishing it. And you may need to stop the app from running to do that. You could also try deploying to a new Azure app and see if it works there.

Comment: @DavidG I've rebuilt the entire solution a few times, with no effect. When I re-deployed an older project today (without any code changes) that has been working fine so far, it also started giving the same error message.

Comment: But if older DLLs exist in the destination, that might cause issues

Comment: @DavidG How do I delete the files in the destination? I tried via Kudu console (CMD), but it wouldn't let me delete (permission denied) some files (especially ProjectName.dll).

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, you may need to stop the app

Comment: Can you please share your code repo if possible ?

Comment: According to error message about `Program.cs:line 65  System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'SDKServices...`, could share the code from Line 60-70.

Comment: @markvgti - Please share your `Program.cs` and `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning out the deployment (deleting any extra files) and changing the target runtime to `win-x64` solved the issue (turns out SDKServices.dll was a 64-bit binary).